# Looping through arrays in JavaScript, finding common occurrences

Tags: javascript, arrays

Every 2.5 seconds I get an array from the server, the array contains user objects. I assign each array to global variable, which after 10 seconds will have 4 arrays containing the following data. I want to check if an user is in all of these arrays, if any user appears in multiple arrays I will then create a single array and loop through, and show it on screen, otherwise discard the arrays. I have data collected. Its like RTLS, making sure that the user was present during 10 second time frame. I cant figure out how to do it in JavaScript. Your insights are highly appreciated. Thank you

```
[
    [
        {
            "id": "6aa35f46-bf31-481e-bac5-a83b012ed1f0",
            "proximity": "NEAR",
            "dateTime": "2017-12-03T14:40:02.5157777",
            "personName": "JOHN"           
        },
        {
           "id": "1b1f7caf-8bed-4f1d-8c71-a83a0131e71c",
            "proximity": "NEAR",
            "dateTime": "2017-12-03T14:40:02.5157777",        
            "personName": "JANE"

        },
        {
            "id": "a6aec29a-a7fa-4d29-82cb-a83b00fedd36",
            "proximity": "NEAR",
            "dateTime": "2017-12-03T14:40:02.5157777",       
            "personName": "Sara",          
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": "6aa35f46-bf31-481e-bac5-a83b012ed1f0",
            "proximity": "NEAR",
            "dateTime": "2017-12-03T14:40:02.5157777",
            "personName": "JOHN"           
        },

        {
            "id": "a6aec29a-a7fa-4d29-82cb-a83b00fedd36",
            "proximity": "NEAR",
            "dateTime": "2017-12-03T14:40:02.5157777",       
            "personName": "JANE"           
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": "6aa35f46-bf31-481e-bac5-a83b012ed1f0",
            "proximity": "NEAR",
            "dateTime": "2017-12-03T14:40:02.5157777",
            "personName": "MIKE"           
        }   ,
        {
            "id": "6aa35f46-bf31-481e-bac5-a83b012ed1f0",
            "proximity": "NEAR",
            "dateTime": "2017-12-03T14:40:02.5157777",
            "personName": "JOHN"           
        },
        {
            "id": "a6aec29a-a7fa-4d29-82cb-a83b00fedd36",
            "proximity": "NEAR",
            "dateTime": "2017-12-03T14:40:02.5157777",       
            "personName": "JANE"           
        }       
    ]
]
```

Comment: It is hard to understand what you want to accomplish from reading your text. Can you clarify "check if an user is in **all** of these arrays, if any user appears in **multiple** arrays" and "create a single array and loop through"?

Comment: "I can't figure out how to do it in JavaScript" how would you do it with another language? What's the problem you are encountering with javascript in particular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple algorithm that detects *if an user is in all of these arrays, if any user appears in multiple arrays*

```js
var data = [
  [{
      "id": "6aa35f46-bf31-481e-bac5-a83b012ed1f0",
      "proximity": "NEAR",
      "dateTime": "2017-12-03T14:40:02.5157777",
      "personName": "JOHN"
    },
    {
      "id": "1b1f7caf-8bed-4f1d-8c71-a83a0131e71c",
      "proximity": "NEAR",
      "dateTime": "2017-12-03T14:40:02.5157777",
      "personName": "JANE"

    },
    {
      "id": "a6aec29a-a7fa-4d29-82cb-a83b00fedd36",
      "proximity": "NEAR",
      "dateTime": "2017-12-03T14:40:02.5157777",
      "personName": "Sara",
    }
  ],
  [{
      "id": "6aa35f46-bf31-481e-bac5-a83b012ed1f0",
      "proximity": "NEAR",
      "dateTime": "2017-12-03T14:40:02.5157777",
      "personName": "JOHN"
    },

    {
      "id": "a6aec29a-a7fa-4d29-82cb-a83b00fedd36",
      "proximity": "NEAR",
      "dateTime": "2017-12-03T14:40:02.5157777",
      "personName": "JANE"
    }
  ],
  [{
    "id": "6aa35f46-bf31-481e-bac5-a83b012ed1f0",
    "proximity": "NEAR",
    "dateTime": "2017-12-03T14:40:02.5157777",
    "personName": "MIKE"
  }]
]

function findCommon(arr, len) {
  const flat = arr
    .map(dimension => dimension.map(e => e.id))
    .reduce((uniq, collection) => {
      collection.forEach(element => {
        if (uniq[element]) uniq[element]++
        else uniq[element] = 1
      });
      return uniq
    }, {})

  return Object.keys(flat).filter(k => flat[k] === len)
}
console.log('present in all', findCommon(data, data.length));
console.log('present in 2', findCommon(data, 2));
```

Comment: This one is close, It checks for only one,  if i put id "6aa35f46-bf31-481e-bac5-a83b012ed1f0" and "1b1f7caf-8bed-4f1d-8c71-a83a0131e71c" in all arrays it returns only one id, any insights? i should return two ids

Comment: updated (`Object.keys(flat).filter(k => flat[k] === len)`), try again

Comment: OP doesn't have experience with javascript. It would be helpful explaining what the code does.

Comment: It works good, just needed to create dictionary to store ids as keys and personName as values. Thanks Medet Tleukabiluly...

Comment: Actually you can tweak script above to return the actual user instead of id

Answer (score 2):

The problem you described has an special property: if any user is contained in all arrays, it would be **present in the first array**.

> To accomplish this, you could use Array#find() if you want a single user, or Array#filter() if you want many.

A second property: if this **user is missing in any array**, you'll discard your arrays.

> To accomplish this, use Array#some(), testing if the outer user (from above) does not belong in any other array. If some() return true, then filter out the user.

Comment: As you can see JOHN and JANE are in all of them and MIKE is in only one, I want to discard any object that is not in all of them. I don't have experience in javascript. I c# there is alot of sugar coating, like extension methods and in built methods can do alot. I don't want to go on wrong track.